# Magento 2.3.4 - Checkout page showing empty

Tags: magento2, cookie, magento2.3.4

We have a magento 2.3.4 running, when you add products to your cart and open the checkout page the page is just blank.

The following error appears within the developer console.

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://paypal.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

What exactly can i do to fix this error?
Here is a link to a screenshot of my "Web" Config settings:

[config settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8kmN.png)

I really would appreciate any help, since i tried everything, i found on google, but there is no specific instructions i can find to get rid of that.
I also upgraded to the latest version (2.3.4), but it did not fix anything.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please check the Exception.log error

Comment: @MohitPatel, there will not be anything in that log, there never is.

Comment: Also forgot to mention, bail if you still can, not even kidding. It just gets worse.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Google had a major break they planned in Chrome, it is caused by how they handle cookie security, and many previous configurations no longer work correctly.  Unfortunately because I'd been working on the site prior to the change, I couldn't truly confirm everything was working prior.

This is the issue, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26840

I did eventually get PayPal Payflow Pro working, by applying a patch linked by one of the github users.

https://gist.github.com/sjb9774/971a28d309dee2f24b853c84e0295693